# Is there an application that automatically tests the system?

Tags: software-recommendation

The System Testing that comes with Ubuntu is cool, but it just takes an enormous amount of time to complete, and I just don't have time to sit around pressing the "Test" button. Is there something that does the tests automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no reliable way for the software to tell if e.g. you can hear a sound or if your screen resolution is what you expect. Therefore you can not have fully automated hardware tests but need someone to tell if the test was successful.

Answer (score 0):

see if you can find"system profiler and benchmarker"  it came with zorin 4, so must be available through synaptic or ubuntu tweak.  works well, useful options to choose from, gives pretty good information that i can understand.